# How do I communicate between GlanceController and InterfaceController in Watchkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/willActivate) for Watchkit one uses `willActivate` to update a glance scene with the most up to date information. What is the recommended way to access that "most up to date" information, or in other-words how do I communicate between the `GlanceController` and the `InterfaceController`? I am currently using Swift but an answer in Obj-C is fine too. 
I cannot seem to find this in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know much about the watchkit but have you any globally accessible objects in which both the glancecontroller and interface controller reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean handoff from a Glance Controller to an Interface Controller?


Coordinating Handoff



 If so you'll want to check out [Coordinating Handoff Activity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW36)

Implement `func handleUserActivity(_ userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)`
on your Initial Interface Controller.

Then a userInfo dictionary to updateUserActivity:userInfo: method and provide a context to transition from Glance -> Watch App.

**Sharing Data** 

 To share the most 'up-to-date' data with your Glance you should be architecting your Watch Extension/iOS Application to be regularly persisting data into a [Shared App Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2408/_index.html) that both your iOS app and Extension can access. When your Glance opens it would simply fetch its data (expected to be the latest) from the shared container and display it.

Comment: Sharing data is what I meant yes. I noticed (since I wrote this question) that apple uses the delegate pattern as well. Does that play a part in implementing the sharing of data?

Comment: @Johnston I understand your thinking, but no. In WatchKit WKInterfaceController's can't be created programmatically. So you won't be able to set a delegate on a WKInterfaceController.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement in your interface controller : - (void)handleUserActivity:(NSDictionary *)userInfo. 
And in the Glance Controller call updateUserActivity:userInfo: with the userInfos you want to pass to your interfaceController.

Answer (score 1):

You can work in glance controller Like working in interface controller to get the "most up to date" information and save the result to NSUserdefault and after that you get back result from NSUserDefault in Interface Controller.